# Ошибка при работе скрипта: "UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy......"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql

Доброе время суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой
Код ошибки:

```
--Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python 39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 761
warnings.warn(
UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
```

а именно когда скрипт работает через IDLE Python "Python 3.9", но с использованием Jupyter Notebook все обрабатывает норм и сохраняет.
Nи кто не сталкивался с такой проблемой, есть выход обойти, как-то игнорировать?

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import csv

# Подключение к БД
def connectToServer():
    try:
        userpwd = '*'
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(*,*,*,encoding='UTF-8')
        with con.cursor() as curs:
            curs.execute('*'; end;')
        return con
    except(Exception,cx_Oracle.IntegrityError) as error:
def readValues(con):
    sql = """

тело запроса

"""
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
    return df
    

con = connectToServer()
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = readValues(con)



df.to_csv(\\*****\****.csv', index=False)

con.close()
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение, что данный коннектор нормально не тестирован. В итоге код не работает или что происходит? И у вас в вопросе что-то с кавычками, код "поехал". Сделайте нормальный

Comment: код работает, если запустить через Jupyter Notebook, но для меня это не вариант, мне нужно чтобы код срабатывал автоматом ежедневно и обходил это предупреждение. Хотел планировщиком задач запускать, через Python IDLE.